# get_family not returning entire family of root node in mptt

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I am using django mptt for tree structure. I ma adding parent to any object while updating not creating any object as shown below .

```
user= User.objects.create(username='abc')
```

after some logics or steps when we are sure that it can be added as a child of some user the I am updating the user instance.

```
User.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).update(parent=parent_user_instance)
```

user is added as the parent and when I'll do `user.get_siblings()` I'll get all **siblings** but when I'll do `user.get_family()` then it fails to fetch its **ancestors** or **descendant** .

**two important things here are :**

1 ) Built in  `User` model (django auth_user) of django is extended to enable mptt .

2 ) I am adding parent through `update()` not `create()` # I am not sure update() have something to do with the issue.

Comment: can you show the error stack along with get_family.

Comment: @AhmedHosny there is no error , get_family return empty array

Comment: so then can you show the implementation of get_family, and how parent is defined in model? and how you get parent_user_instance? it is also better to use `.get(pk=user.pk)` rather than `filter`

Comment: @AhmedHosny issue resolved , you can check [here](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/432) the complete problem and solution